# How to make namedtuple when column headers have spaces

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a namedtuple from a DictReader object. My code looks like this. The problem I'm struggling with is I have some really long and ugly column headers in the csv file I'm working with.  For the sake of this example, one of the column headers I am working with is:

"What is typically the main dish at your Thanksgiving dinner?".

What is throwing me off is there are a bunch of spaces in this title, so if I understand correctly, the namedtuple thinks these are all arguments. What way would you recommend to solve this? I have referenced several threads and feel like I almost got there through this one: [What is the pythonic way to read CSV file data as rows of namedtuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007174/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-read-csv-file-data-as-rows-of-namedtuples)

I am just using one column header as an example. Here is some code I have so far:

```
import csv
import collections

filename = 'thanksgiving2015.csv'
with open(filename, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    columns = collections.namedtuple('columns', 
    'What is typically the main dish at your 
    Thanksgiving dinner?')
```

Should I strip all these column headers of their spaces before making the namedtuple? I could do this before I even import the csv in excel, but I assume there is a nice solution in python.

Comment: Why do you want to use namedtuple, though?  Why not read into a list of dicts?

Answer (score 1):

`namedtuple` treats a single string as a white-space-delimited list of field names. You need to pass an explicit list of column names instead.

```
namedtuple('columns', ['What is...', 'some other absurd column name'])
```

I would rethink using the header values directly as field names, though. Ignore the header, and pass a list of shorter names that you can use as attributes later.

Comment: How would I pass a list of shorter names that I can use as attributes later?

Comment: I mean something like `Columns = namedtuple('columns', 'foo bar bar')`, so that later when you have something like `x = Columns(...)`, you can write `x.foo`, `x.bar`, etc. `x.'What is typically the main dish at your Thanksgiving dinner?'` isn't syntactically valid.

Comment: Yes, I have also been trying to do this, but have tried an failed as well.  Can you give me a quick example of how to do it?

Comment: I did; it's the very first piece of code in my comment. Pick the names you want, then pass either a list of those names or a single whitespace-delimited string as the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

As chepner pointed out, the second argument of nametuple() can either be a space-separated string or a list of strings like:

```
columns = collections.namedtuple('columns', 
    ['What is typically the main dish at your Thanksgiving dinner?', 'other column'])
```

However, doing so will fail with:

```
ValueError: Type names and field names must be valid identifiers
```

This is because `columns` (which you should capitalize as `Columns`) will be an object with 'What is typically...' as an identifier and identifiers can't have spaces. To be clear, you would use it as:

```
Columns = namedtuple('columns', ['what is', 'this'])
columns = Columns('foo', 'bar')
print(columns.this) #  Works fine
print(columns.what is) #  Not going to work
```

If you were using a simple dict(), you would write:

```
print(columns['what is'])
```

You can however ask namedtuple to rename invalid identifiers:

```
Columns = namedtuple('columns', ['what is', 'this'], rename=True)
print(columns._0)  # ugly but valid
print(columns.this)
```